# Installation of Sitecore 9.0 Failing on WebDeploy

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I'm having an issue while installing Sitecore 9.0 on my local machine. I'm not sure what the issue is since I've had success installing it in the past. I also have multiple issues of 9.0.1 installed. I've found people having the same issue while installing 9.0.1 with configuration for Sitecore 9.0, but that's not the issue I'm having since I downloaded a clean installation package right before the install. I'm at a loss for the reason right now, the only thing I can think of that may be a cause is that I just updated SSMS to the most recent versions in order to be able to install BACPAC files from an azure environment. I was wondering if anyone else has come across this issue. The exact error message I'm getting from powershell is:

```
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- InstallWDP : WebDeploy ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
msdeploy.exe : Error: Source does not support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name'. Must be one of (Application Path, Sitecore Admin New Password, Database Server Name, Database 
Admin User Name, Database Admin User Password, Core DB Name, Master DB Name, Web DB Name, Reporting DB Name, XDB Reference Data DB Name, Experience Forms DB Name, Marketing Automation DB 
Name, Processing Pools DB Name, Processing Tasks DB Name, Core DB User Name, Core DB User Password, Master DB User Name, Master DB User Password, Web DB User Name, Web DB User Password, 
Reporting DB User Name, Reporting DB User Password, XDB Reference Data DB User Name, XDB Reference Data DB User Password, Experience Forms DB User Name, Experience Forms DB User Password, 
Marketing Automation DB User Name, Marketing Automation DB User Password, Processing Pools DB User Name, Processing Pools DB User Password, Processing Tasks DB User Name, Processing Tasks 
DB User Password, Core Admin Connection String, Master Admin Connection String, Web Admin Connection String, Experience Forms Admin Connection String, Reporting Admin Connection String, 
Processing Tasks Admin Connection String, Master Connection String, Core Connection String, Web Connection String, XDB Reference Data Connection String, Experience Forms Connection String, 
Reporting Connection String, SOLR Connection String, XConnect Collection, XDB Reference Data Client, XDB MA Connection String, XDB MA Reporting Client, XDB MA Ops Client, Processing Pools 
Connection String, Processing Tasks Connection String, XConnect Server Certificate Validation Thumbprint, XConnect Collection Certificate, XDB Reference Data Client Certificate, XDB MA 
Reporting Client Certificate, XDB MA Ops Client Certificate, Data Folder, Solr Core Index Name, Solr Master Index Name, Solr Web Index Name, Solr Testing Index Name, Solr Suggested Index 
Name, Solr FXM Master Index Name, Solr FXM Web Index Name, Solr Marketing Asset Master Index Name, Solr Marketing Asset Web Index Name, Solr Marketing Definitions Master Index Name, Solr 
Marketing Definitions Web Index Name).
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31 char:13
+             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Source d...eb Index Name).:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error count: 1.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\path\install.ps1:51 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:07
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\WINDOWS\system32\xconnect-xp0.180615 (8).log
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36 char:2
+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is from msdeploy. It's trying to communicate that the package your are installing does not have the 'IIS Web Application Name', it then provides the list of parameters the package does have.

The SIF configuration will pass a bunch of parameters to msdeploy, but you need to provide the correct path to the WDP package.

It looks like in your xconnectparams block you are either passing the wrong WDP to the xconnect config, or using the wrong config with the xconnect wdp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the following step are properly done, before installing it again:

- VS 2017 should be installed, (which pretty much installs everything necessary for sitecore deployment and build)
- Latest build tools to be installed ( MS Deploy build tools version 15)
- Remove all the datebases.
- Rewrite module to be installed correctly
- The Sitcore PSGallery and SitecoreGallery should be Trusted Repo
- Remove the IIS directory.
- Rerun the install

I have also compiled the list of commands for the powershell, that are prerequisites for the SC9 installation

https://gist.github.com/isaadansari/63bd6ee4a1a80b40dcc0113739f4bb1b

For more help check out my blog, for easy insatllation guide

https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/